# Get a user's keyboard input that was requested by another function

Tags: python-3.x, input

I am using a python package for database managing. The provided class has a method `delete()` that deletes a record from the database. Before deleting, it asks a user to verify the operation from a console, e.g. `Proceed? [yes, No]:`

My function needs to perform other actions depending on whether a user chose to delete a record. Can I get user's input requested by the function from the package?

Toy example:

```
def ModuleFunc():
    while True:
        a=input('Proceed? [yes, No]:')
        if a in ['yes','No']:
            #Perform some actions behind a hood
            return
```

This function will wait for one of the two responses and return None once it gets either. After calling this function, can I determine the User's response (without modifying this function)? I think a modification of the Package's source code is not a good idea in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just patch the class at runtime? Say you had a file `./lib/db.py` defining a class `DB` like this:

```
class DB:
  def __init__(self):
    pass

  def confirm(self, msg):
    a=input(msg + ' [Y, N]:')
    if a == 'Y':
      return True
    return False

  def delete(self):
    if self.confirm('Delete?'):
        print ('Deleted!')
    return
```

Then in `main.py` you could do:

```
from lib.db import DB

def newDelete(self):
  if self.confirm('Delete?'):
    print('Do some more stuff!')
    print('Deleted!')
  return

DB.delete = newDelete
test = DB()
test.delete()
```

See it working [here](https://repl.it/repls/NimbleFeminineApplicationprogram)

Answer (score 1):

I would save key events to somewhere(file or memory) with something like Keylogger. Then, you will be able to reuse last one.

However, if you can modify module package  and redistribute, it would be easier.

```
Return
```

To

```
Return a
```